# I cannot print in colour through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, printing, excel-2010

I recorded a macro that prints sheets 2 and 3. I am selecting the whole workbook and printing pages 2 and 3 since there seems to be no way to print individual sheets. After recording the macro, I also added popups to select the printer (printer setup dialog) and an inputbox for the number of copies that the user wants to print. The following is the code.

```
Sub Print_Plan()

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

Dim number As String
number = InputBox("How many copies do you want", , 1)
If number = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

Sheet1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$BS$50"

ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=2, To:=3, Copies:=number, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

The user also wants to print in colour. The problem here is that the colour option can only be selected from the printer properties.[image: Printer Setup and Properties]

I noticed that it is possible to open print properties from the print setup by clicking on the setup button. But even if I choose colour, it doesn't print in colour. Plus, I haven't found a way to open print properties any other way. I have even added `black and white = false` and yet it prints black and white.

How do I change the code so the user is able to choose colour print?

Comment: You said even if you choose colour, it doesn't print that way. Where did you choose that?

Comment: Have you tried printing a color document manually?  ***You need to get that working first.***

Comment: ...also you shouldn't need to set your print properties programmatically.   Your printer has a way to set print defaults (that will "stay set"), and Windows printer settings probably has a related setting-or-two as well.  If you can't *manually* print something in color then this is *not* a programming-related problem. (Perhaps https://superuser.com/ ?)

Comment: When "Xerox Black and White" is not selected, it prints in colour. And I have tried printing colour manually.

Comment: That is true, I can set it as his default setting. I will test it when he comes back to work tomorrow :) Thank you.